# How do I force a float and int to have a decimal point or trailing zeros

Tags: c#

I am trying to interface with a machine over RS232 and the machine requires all input to have a decimal separator or else it assumes the decimal position. E.G. If I send `25` it will interpret that as `0.025`, but `25.000` or `25.` will be received properly as `25.000`

I tried [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Round(v=VS.110).aspx) but for whole number values it doesn't include the trailing zeros.

So, if I have

```
float a = 90;
float b = cos(24);
comPort.WriteLine("G01 A" + a + " B" + b);
```

What do I need to add so that it forces 3 decimals places? I'm not concerned about how it's rounded nor if it truncated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use string formatting. All the info you need is on the following MSDN pages:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for the most common formats
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) if you require something else

```
float a = 90;
float b = cos(24);
comPort.WriteLine("G01 A{0:F3} B{1:F3}", a, b);
```

`F3` means fixed point with 3 digits of precision after the decimal separator.

This works if `comPort` is something like a `TextWriter`, because this class has a [`WriteLine` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60scc1f1.aspx) which supports formatting. If you're using `SerialPort` directly, you don't get that overload, and you have to put `string.Format` explicitly in there:

```
comPort.WriteLine(string.Format("G01 A{0:F3} B{1:F3}", a, b));
```

Some equivalent ways to write the same thing:

```
comPort.WriteLine("G01 A{0:0.000} B{1:0.000}", a, b);
```

Or in C#6:

```
comPort.WriteLine($"G01 A{a:F3} B{b:F3}");
```

That one will get translated to the following by the compiler:

```
comPort.WriteLine(string.Format("G01 A{0:F3} B{1:F3}", a, b));
```

Comment: Thank you for the references and the explanations! Also would like to add that including # in the 0.000## would allow optional additional decimal places. In case someone else needs this information later on. My machine does not support more than 3 places though.

Answer (score 4):

Use the ToString() method on a and b like this:

```
comPort.WriteLine("G01 A" + a.ToString("F3") + " B" + b.ToString("F3"));
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using concatenation, use String.Format

```
comPort.WriteLine(String.Format("G01 A{0:F3} B{1:F3}", a, b));
```

Comment: Is the String.Format part required?

Comment: I can't be sure what the signature on the comPort.WriteLine() is :) If it is a SerialPort, then yes, String.Format is required.
Many TextWriter implementations can accept a format parameter then a list of arguments, so if this comPort object supports it, you would not need to wrap with String.Format

Comment: Once you start using String.Format you will find the added benefit of code analysis checking that you have actually specified the right number of arguments to match your format parameter, a glitch like that goes unnoticed until runtime if you get that wrong. :)